# Profiler Flame Chart in Angular not showing my functions

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, zonejs

This is what my profiler is showing for an Angular 7 app, built with angular-cli.

[image: profiler schreenshot]

### Every function call is bundled under `zone.js`, and I cannot get useful information on what runs and for how long.

---

The app is running with: `ng serve`, and *I think* is in debug mode:

in main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  console.log('production mode!');
  enableProdMode();
} else {
  console.log('debug mode!');
```

At runtime, `enableProdMode()` doesn't get called.

I thought that my `angular.json` configures webpack to run in production mode, but it is the exact same as a new project with `ng new` (diff'ed them), except adding some external scripts + scss files.

Comment: Looks like sourcemaps aren't generated or aren't recognized/used by devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm good idea. I tried it with `ng serve --source-map` and it didn't have any difference. Also, sourcemaps must work, because the Sources tab properly shows my code, not the bundled one.

Comment: Same issue here, but with Vue.js. And sourcemaps work in the sources tab...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool I was looking for is now called Javascript Profiler in chrome Dev Tools (it's hidden in the three dots menu on the top right).

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, but it's such a hassle! Is there anyway to get it back in the Performance tab?

Comment: No unfortunately, they are separate features now.

Comment: Damn, that's such a pain. Especially because the CPU throttling option is in the Performance tab